# How to preserve color when writing to stdout

Tags: haskell, conduit

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack --install-ghc --resolver lts-8.8 runghc
-}
import System.IO
import System.Process

main = createProcess (proc "ls" [])
```

Although `stdout` is considered by Haskell as a tty, as `hIsTerminalDevice stdout` returns `True`, `ls` doesn't recognize it as so, and doesn't output colors.

Is there a way to circumvent this or is it plainly impossible to get color output working in Haskell ?

EDIT: to be clear, I don't want just `ls` to work, but the whole range of Unix tools that support color output when they identify `stdout` as a tty.

Comment: `ls` doesn’t produce color output by default. Use `"ls" ["--color=auto"]` if your `ls` supports that.

Comment: Can't do that. I'm implementing a shell and I don't choose what the user will type. However, type `ls` in `bash` and you'll see colors by default.

Comment: @SebastienGuimmara Try typing `which ls`. It might be an alias set in one of bash's configuration files.

Comment: @sepp2k ha ! You were both right, my mistake !

Comment: To be clear: `ls` *does* detect stdin as a tty when run through `createProcess`. Otherwise it wouldn't work with `--color=auto` either ("auto" means "use color in a tty and no color otherwise").

Comment: Indeed, I had an aliased `ls` and I had no idea. My mistake.

Comment: Although it is not the problem with piping to `ls`, many consoles support ANSI or `xterm` color codes, which you can output by inserting escape sequences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is Haskell is not at fault, I was confusing my own `ls`, which was aliased to `ls --color=tty`.